# Robustness Checks in Presence of Stambaugh Bias

Tags: forecasting, bias, robust

If we were performing a forecasting exercise and found predictability (or Stambaugh Bias), what are a few approaches we could take to checking the robustness of our findings?

Comment: The question is too brief and too broad.